# How can i test if a certain table view cell has a certain image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, tableview

In my app, you can add and delete cells. I only want the user to be able to add 1 of each cell. So, is there a way to test if a cell already has a certain image?

like:

```
if(myTableView.cell.imageView == @"image.png"){
// do something
}
```

Please help! THanks

***EDIT***

This button allows us to add the cells and the images to the new cells.

```
  - (IBAction)outlet1:(id)sender {
if (cart.cell.tag == 1) {
    UIAlertView * alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"You have already added this" message:@"Go to My Cart and add more if you like" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Done" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
else {
[cart.cells addObject:@"1"];
 [[cart.cells lastObject] setTag:1];
UIImage * myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle1.png"];
[cart.imageArray addObject:myImage];
```

}
    }

so i basically want to test if this cell has been added already!

Comment: Can you show the code that sets or adds the image to the cell?

Comment: The nature of your question reveals flaws with your app's design.  *You* are creating these cells.  *You* are setting the image of these cells.  Thus, at one point *you knew* which image went in the cell.  **Why have you forgotten this**?  You shouldn't store model information in your views; your views should *reflect* your model.  Thus, the real answer to this question is: restructure your app so that you can remember this information elsewhere.  Don't rely on the cell to remember it for you.

Comment: How do you assign cart.cell? anyway you should not check the tag of cart.cell you should check the tag of [cart.cells lastObject] in the above code.

Comment: What do you mean by assign cart.cell? Like how do i assign its text? And okay So you mean test if `[cart.cells.tag lastObject];`? or do i leave out the `.tag`? THanks for all the help !!:D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have a few different images than you don't need to check for an image, rather you should set a tag number to the cell that corresponds to an image using 
[cell setTag:(int)]; so paddle2.png can be 2 and paddle1.png can be 1 and you would [cell setTag:1] for paddle1.png . Than when testing simply check the tag:

If ([cell tag] == 1) {
    //do something
  }

here is the code for your button:

```
   - (IBAction)outlet2:(id)sender {
[cart.cells addObject:@"1"];
[[cart.cells lastObject] setTag:2];
UIImage * myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"paddle2.png"];
[cart.imageArray addObject:myImage];
}
```

and here is the test code:

```
if(myTableView.cell.tag == 2){
// do something
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help man! :) ok i added this and it isnt working. I am trying to add a cell and test if that cell has been added later in the app. So if i update my question, could you take a look at it please and let me know if its right? The app crashes now? Thanks:)

Comment: The code you rewrote above does not make sense...  I know that cart.cells is an array but what is cart.cell?

Comment: right cart.cells is the array. and cart.cell is just dealing with the table view cell.

Comment: How are you assigning cart.cell?

Comment: Also. Please note the comment I made above and those of Dave DeLong

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you cannot check for an image name, but you can keep an array of the images names that are stored in the cells.  Then you can check the index of the row and the index of the image array names to see if it is what you are looking for:

```
if ([[[myimages objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"ImageName"] isEqualToString:@"image.png"])
{
   // you got what you were looking for,
}
```

'i' above would be the indexPath.row value - I am assuming that you are check this on the delegate method didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: ok if i already add the images to an array, how could i test it that way? Thanks for the reply man! :)